Get all dates when a certain activity is booked in google sheets

As you can see this sheet screenshot attached, I want to extract all the dates under which a certain name occurs. for eg. "srna" comes under 05.08,07,08 and 09.08 basically these are bookings under certain dates, and i want to generate a receipt which will gave the date, and calculate the cost from another table.
I am not sure where to start. Lookup doesn't seem to be a solution here


Here's one approach you may test out:
=filter(D2:K2;bycol(D3:K;lambda(Σ;xmatch("Srna";Σ))))



try:
=SORT(TOCOL(IF(D3:K="Srna"; D2:K2; ); 1))


you can change TOCOL to TOROW if you need
